# Avoid FocusOut event trigerred when apllication loses focus

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have done an override of the standard TextInput component
In this component I have :

```
addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, handleFocusOut );
```

- My method is triggered when the field loses focus for another field (nice)
- Problem : It is triggered also when the whole flex application loses focus (when my field has the current focus inside my form)

Questions :

- What have I done wrong ?
- Is there a way to avoid doing stuff when it is a application-focusout-event ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this is behaving this way. But one solution might be to have an eventListener for `FOCUS_OUT` event at the application level and call `stopImmediatePropagation().`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help !
Here is what I have done in my component (textinput child)

Add two event handler :
- addEventListener( Event.ACTIVATE, handleEventActivate );
- addEventListener( Event.DEACTIVATE, handleEventDeActivate );

They update the internal field _isApplicationActive
I handle the focusOut event :
addEventListener( FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, handleFocusOut );
in the method I have
if (!_isApplicationActive) { event.stopImmediatePropagation(); }

With this my focusOut handling functions are not called when the app is deactivated
Because => DECACTIVATE events are called before FocusOut events !

Comment: stopImmediatePropagation cause minor problems on the inputtext : you need to click in it to regain the blue focus border (switching back to the application is not enough)

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to check if [`event.relatedObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html#relatedObject) (the object receiving focus) is null. Flex's `FocusManager` tries really hard to ensure *some* flex object has (flex) focus, so it should not be null otherwise.

Do also check [`isRelatedObjectInaccessible`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html#isRelatedObjectInaccessible) if you might need to.